# How to add value with $ character to mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

```
"FinalizeFunction" : null, 
"FilterDefinition" : {
    "hour" : NumberInt(7), 
    "hostname" : {
        "$exists" : true
    }
}, 
"SortDefinition" : {
    "hostname" : NumberInt(1)
}
```

I want to add this document to mongodb collection, but i get following error:

```
Document field names can't start with '$' (Bad Key: '$exists')
```

Actually, i want to use this document for generating map-reduce function in code side. So i need BsonDocument for FilterDefinition like this.

Comment: Why do you need the $ on that field name? Can you not just remove it form your programming?

Comment: I need this field for filtering in C#. '$' is special char for operator definition in mongo.

Comment: Yes, that is why you cannot save the document. There is no way aroun  d this

Comment: Thanks for reply. Solved it keeping BsonDocument as string `"{ 'hour' : 7, 'hostname': { $exists: true } }"` and in c# side parsed string to BsonDocument with parse method. `BsonDocument.Parse(string)`

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately you can not have a filed name with $ sign. here is some restriction on document

- The field name _id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value
  must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and may be of any
  type other than an array.
- The field names cannot start with the dollar sign ($) character.
- The field names cannot contain the dot (.) character.
- The field names cannot contain the null character.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/

Comment: Thanks for answer Rohit. I solved it keeping BsonDocument as string.